# Keras Dense layer after an LSTM with return_sequence=True

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning, nlp

I am trying to reimplement this paper [1](http://aclweb.org/anthology/D18-1060) in Keras as the authors used PyTorch [2](https://github.com/gao-g/metaphor-in-context/). Here is the network architecture: 
[image]
What I have done so far is:

```
number_of_output_classes = 1
hidden_size = 100
direc = 2
lstm_layer=Bidirectional(LSTM(hidden_size, dropout=0.2, return_sequences=True))(combined) #shape after this step (None, 200) 
#weighted sum and attention should be here
attention = Dense(hidden_size*direc, activation='linear')(lstm_layer) #failed trial
drop_out_layer = Dropout(0.2)(attention)    
output_layer=Dense(1,activation='sigmoid')(drop_out_layer) #shape after this step (None, 1)
```

I want to include the attention layer and the final FF layer after the LSTM but I am running into errors due to the dimensions and the return_sequence= True option.

Comment: Any github repository from where you can share your code

Answer (score 0):

This is a sequence classification task. Sequence classification is many to one mapping, where sequential input from is labeled to a single class. In this case, your inputs should have a shape of (batch_size, time_steps, channels) and outputs should have a shape of (batch_size, channels). If the `return_sequences` argument of LSTM class is True, the output will have a shape of `(batch_size, time_steps, channels)`. Feeding this to dense layers and dropout layer wouldn't reduce the number of dimensions. To reduce the number of dimension to 2 you have to set `return_sequences` argument of last LSTM layer to `False`. In your case

```py
lstm_layer=Bidirectional(LSTM(hidden_size, dropout=0.2, return_sequences=False))(combined)
```

Comment: Thanks Mitiku for your reply. But as I understood from the figure that the output is a sequence as well. Then combine it, right?

Comment: Not really. In the paper figure 2 is sentence labeling, i.e sequence to label mapping and the output is not sequence rather it is a single word. For sequence to sequence mapping look figure 1 of the paper you mentioned.

Comment: @Mitiku : Good answer, but I think you meant to say "To reduce the number of dimension into two you have to set return_sequences argument of last LSTM layer to False." instead of True is that correct?